# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? (3)

Tags: пунктуация

В служебном помещении цеха СП, на дефростации, находилась продукция СП высокой степени готовности. При проверке журнала дефростации, информация о дате, времени и наименовании продукции, находящейся на дефростации, отсутствовала, данные были внесены во время проверки.

Answer (score 1):

*В служебном помещении цеха СП, **на дефростации**, находилась продукция СП высокой степени готовности. **При проверке журнала дефростации** информация о дате, времени и наименовании продукции, находящейся на дефростации, отсутствовала, данные были внесены во время проверки.*

Пояснение

1) Обстоятельство ***на дефростации*** (= на размораживании) обособляется, так как имеет значение уточнения (= на технологической операции дефростации).

2) Обстоятельственный оборот ***при проверке журнала дефростации*** не обособляется,  так как он  выражен падежной формой существительного и  находится в начале предложения (относится ко всему предложению).